# Ion-autocomplete: show all elements before userinput

Tags: android, angularjs, autocomplete, ionic-framework

When using `ion-autocomplete` the list of possibilities is empty until the user enters a character.

Is there a way to show all possibilities before the user enters a char?

example: http://codepen.io/guylabs/pen/GJmwMw

The array in the controller is filled, but only displayed if the user enters at least once a char.

Comment: github issue: https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete/issues/57

Comment: The issue `#57` has been solved and you can use the master to test it.

Comment: I use a function to filter the results and i also use it to to prePopulate the list => If the request String is empty i get all objects. So i tried ` search-items="idAutocomplete('','species')" ` which ended in a digestLoop. Could this be, because i request the objects from the backend (List is empty in the beginning) and is there a way to populate the list when the user opens it?

Comment: well it seems that the digest loop is happening always if i use a function. Tried it with one, which returns an empty array

Comment: Well the problem is that the `search-items` attribute is mapped as a two way binded value and not as an expression/function. So you need to set the value when you resolve the promise from the backend. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Nice it works but does it also update if the `search-items` changes (if i load data depending on what the user does) ? Also if i select an item and then delete it, the list is empty again.

Comment: Just tested it, the `search-items` updates ;)

Comment: Ok good. Yes the `search-items` gets cleared when you select an option. The idea of this is to just show an initial list and then when the user wants to search something else the `items-method` gets called.

Comment: Is there then another method to populate the list if the user deleted the only item in single select mode?

Comment: Currently there is no functionality. But why do you need this if you always show the same list? Then you could use a static select list where all items are shown. 

You can also use the https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete#the-items-removed-method callback to populate the `search-items` list again then you have the functionality you need.

Comment: Well stupid me, haven't thought of using the `items-removed-method`. Just implemented it and it's working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

you can filter tag to display all list without entering any character.
Am providing a sample code as

```
<div ng-init="friends = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                         {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                         {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                         {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                         {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                         {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}]"></div>

<label>Search: <input ng-model="searchText"></label>
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:searchText">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.phone}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Having any queries reply back